# UIImagePickerController cause Leaks after taking 2 3 pictures in swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making a custom view of camera, in which i'm taking photos from gallery and from camera, photo gallery works ok, but camera is not working fine, I'm using UIImagePickerController for it, after taking 3 4 pictures it causes memory leaks and shut down the app, i'm properly presentingviewcontroller and dissmissingviewcontroller but it creates memory leaks issues anyway, i Used leak instrument to track down the issue and i found that UIImagePickerController creats new instance every time it appears to take photo

```
       Avfoundation -[AVCapturePhotoOutput init]
       NSSmutableArray Avfoundation -[[AVCapturePhotoOutput init]
```

please guide me how can i resolve it? because I'm not good in managing memory leaks.

**Edit:**
   this is didfinishdelegate method!

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{

        self.delegate?.didFinishTakingPhoto(image)
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
           self.popMe(false)
        })
```

}
    }

```
    func didFinishTakingPhoto(image: UIImage)
       {
    self.imageView.image = image;
    self.startActivity("", detailMsg: "")
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) { () -> Void in

        if let chokusItem = self.item {
            var size = CGSizeMake(600.0, CGFloat.max)
            if Global.shared.highQualityPhotoEnables {
                size.width = 900.0
            }
            let scaledImage = self.imageView.image!.resizedImageWithContentMode(UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit, bounds: size, interpolationQuality: CGInterpolationQuality.High)
            let thumbSize = CGSizeMake(80.0, CGFloat.max)
            self.thumbImage = self.imageView.image!.resizedImageWithContentMode(UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit, bounds: thumbSize, interpolationQuality: CGInterpolationQuality.High)

            self.photo = PhotoViewModel(image: scaledImage, parent: chokusItem)

            let delay = 0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.imageView.image = scaledImage
                self.stopActivity()
                self.removeCommentTableViews()
                self.removeCommentViews()
                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
                self.showPhotoLimitAlertIfRequired()
            })
            if Global.shared.shouldSavePhotoToGallery {

                let assetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
                assetsLibrary.saveImage(scaledImage, toAlbum: "Inspection Images", completion: { (url, error) -> Void in
                    print("success", terminator: "")
                    }, failure: { (error) -> Void in
                        print("failure", terminator: "")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code in the didFinishPickingImage delegate?

Comment: @ebby94 i've edited my post..

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be some kind of bug in iOS , I am not sure however, I got pointed to this thread after making my own question, since I didn't find this one.

However, I am initializing my code in a completely different way than you but the leaked object appears the same.

I have opened a radar to this on:
https://openradar.appspot.com/29495120

You can also see my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111899/avcapturephotooutput-memory-leak-ios

Hope this answer atleast gives you some less headache wasting time while I am awaiting a confirmation.